Android override default NavHost Transition
I have set up a Bottom App Bar for navigation with the NavController and the NavHost in jetpack compose like this:
Scaffold (
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = appName)
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                BottomNavigationItem().bottomNavigationItems().forEachIndexed { index,
                                                                                navigationItem ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = index == navigationSelectedItem,
                        label = {Text(navigationItem.label)},
                        icon = {
                            if (index == navigationSelectedItem) {
                                Icon(
                                    navigationItem.filledIcon,
                                    contentDescription = navigationItem.label
                                )
                            } else {
                                Icon(
                                    navigationItem.outlinedIcon,
                                    contentDescription = navigationItem.label
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            navigationSelectedItem = index
                            navController.navigate(navigationItem.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        },
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.statusBars)
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screens.Home.route,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = it)
        ) {
            composable(
                Screens.History.route,
            ) {
                navigationSelectedItem = 0
                HistoryScreen(state)
            }
            composable(
                Screens.Home.route,
            ) {
                navigationSelectedItem = 1
                HomeScreen(state)
            }
            composable(
                Screens.Reminders.route,
            ) {
                navigationSelectedItem = 2
                RemindersScreen(state)
            }
        }
    }

The Screens.History is just a String in this case and the different HistoryScreen etc. are just composables with the content of the pages. Everything works well, except for the animations. I don't know how to override this, as it seems, default animation:
https://imgur.com/LcbwCO7
I have tried to set the exit and enter transitions of both the composables and the nav host itself, but the animation stays. Do you have any suggestion of how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I was facing the same issue with the navigation screen transition. It's a bug in the Compose Navigation library. Try to update the androidx.navigation:navigation-compose on version 2.8.0-alpha04 that provides a lot of fixies described here  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297258205#comment1
